# What's the correct syntax for using an IP address in xcopy?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, xcopy

I want to copy a set of files on a Windows computer to a number of Windows servers I have credentials for without having to go through RDC, theoretically a simple task. For this usage, the appropriate syntax in xcopy is apparently `\\servername\...`, but I don't think I have anything to put in for `servername` -- just the IP address and password. And `xcopy "C:\Users\myname\Documents\uploadtest.txt" "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\"` just gives the result "Invalid drive specification" instead of requesting a password or anything. Same if the second colon is replaced with a dollar sign. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see now that you say you've already tried with `C$` and that didn't work either. Can you browse to `\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\C$\Users\Public\Public Documents` in windows explorer?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Eventually I got a "Network error" popup: "Windows cannot access \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\C$\Users\Public\Public Documents\".

Comment: can you browse to `\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\ ` at all? Is Windows File & Printer Sharing enabled on the remote server?

Comment: No to the Explorer browsing. Network discovery on the server is turned off; file and printer sharing is turned on.

Comment: It may be a firewall issue. Try disabling all firewalls on the server and see if that works.

Comment: What if you use the `copy` command, for just one file. Does it work?

Comment: `copy` doesn't work. The error message there is `The network path was not found.`

Comment: did you check the firewalls? This is clearly a network issue. You need to be able to browse to the path in Windows Explorer first. Before that, nothing else will work, I guarantee it.

Comment: @ShayGuy: See the answer I provided. Without the sharing protocol enabled, you won't be able to share files, even if your firewall rules are configured properly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the `\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\C:\Users` with `\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\C$\Users` and your command should work. `xcopy` only knows about shared folders and the `C:` drive is shared as `C$` automatically.

Comment: +1.  But, mostly correct.  The C$ share is for users with administrative access to that machine, or those given explicit access

Answer (score 0):

From [Ensure that File and Printer Sharing is Enabled](http://www.nowiressecurity.com/articles/troubleshooting_network_sharing_issues.htm) section at nowiressecurity.com:

> On Windows computers, the sharing protocols for network connections or
>   adapters must be enabled for that particular computer to host and
>   access network shares. Although firewall configurations and other
>   settings might be enabled, sharing is not possible unless these
>   protocols are enabled.